# How to sign Android application with RSA key

Tags: android

I don't have original keystore file, it is lost by my colleague, I have just RSA key from application. Is it possible to sign new apk version with this RSA key?

**EDIT:** I have ***public*** RSA key

Comment: http://smartphonesandroid.org/how-to-submit-your-application-to-google-play/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a public key as well because:

```
Keystore = private + public key pair = identified by an alias
```

Try to generate a public key from your private key, then package the pair in a keystore. The java keytool should be able to do this. See : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/keytool.html

Comment: I have just public key. Is it enough, or I need private key instead, generate public key using this private one, and create keystore using this keys?

Comment: You cannot generate private key from public key, but you can generate public keys from private key.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this serves your purpose.

http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2293-how-to-sign-your-android-app/

You can also use ADT for your task, see this

http://tordtech.blogspot.in/2009/10/signing-android-applications.html