# How to recreate the keystore file if it got deleted accidentally

Tags: android, certificate, key, sign, recreate

I have an app which is signed and several keystore files. I'd like to update the app, so I need to find out which one of keys was used.

[image]

- How to recreate the keystore file if it got deleted accidentally.

I have recovered it but I want to generate the keystore file again.

> I know the user name & password also.

---

Simply my question is :

### How to convert `.RSA` file to `.JKS`

Please Help

Comment: If you lost keystore then , your playstore never allow to upadate your app with new keystore . It always conceder as a new application.

Comment: Any chances if any As `my old app have many users and good reviews.`

Comment: You can't. Lesson learned in a hard way, I also learn it in that way ;)

Comment: @Mij this it not at all funny, I am very sad. :-(

Comment: it's ipmossible to restore a keystore file after it has been deleted.

Comment: I won' t say that its **impossible** but It may be [very difficult](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/keytool.html)  to do that, still if you have the `.RSA` file with you which you extracted it from signed apk of playstore. http://tordtech.blogspot.in/2009/10/signing-android-applications.html As this would be violation of google playstore security :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you lost your keystore then it is gone forever, you can't do anything with that...

if you have your keystore (and log/pass, if not [you may try bruteforce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149530/forgot-keystore-password-thinking-of-brute-force-detection-will-it-corrupt-the)) then you can try sign your apk with every key and check fingerprint matches version from Google Play (you can "extract" APK installed on device). note that there is also possiblity of multi-signing APK, but Google Play allows only single one, so it's not for you...

Having only RSA signature (extracted from prev signed APK?) is not sufficient at all, it is only "public" part of keystore, which may be extracted by everyone. you need "private" part, which is stored in your keystore only.

[keytool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/keytool.html) is tool for playing with keystores - generating keys, signing files, recovering "public" key etc. but in your case it will be useless probably. Just find this damn keystore... Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, I have the `.RSA` file with me, any hope in that case?

Comment: have you checked [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16562850/how-to-sign-android-application-with-rsa-key) topic? keystore is "sum" of private and public key. you can try to re-create/produce "new" public key from private key, but not private from public, obviusly (it wouldn't be so secure then)... Do your best and find this file, I'm affraid that this is your only hope... Good luck!

Comment: Can you edit the answer and post the steps you just told. thanks  I will accept that.